# Java Eclipse WindowBuilder - where is the user interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I installed WindowBuilder and I'm trying to start using it. The instructions say "Choose an appropriate layout manager for your window." but don't say how to do that. There is supposed to be a "palette" somewhere in Eclipse but I can't find it anywhere. Am I supposed to launch WindowBuilder from outside Eclipse or is there some series of clicks within Eclipse to get to it? I have gone through all the documentation and every instruction assumes you already have the design tools open and active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very simple, when you see your code (*assuming you use eclipse*)
there is a bar just above the console window (*if you haven't moved it*) that says DESIGN.

Comment: It would be nice if they would put this step anywhere in the documentation. I read every section and there was no mention of how to get to this.